# Viewing & adding PDF to database simultaneously

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pdf, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

At the moment I am converting the data on the page to PDF this way:

```
<cfdocument format="PDF">
  <cfoutput>
    #pageContent#
  </cfoutput>
</cfdocument>
```

With `#pageContent#` being a variable created using `cfsavecontent`

The way it works is that I have a 'Export to PDF' link at the bottom of the page which contains a url variable - this link directs to the same page but the variable passed in tells it to output the PDF.

My question is, when the link is clicked to create the PDF, is there a way to upload the PDF to the database at the same time?

I know I have to use `cffile action="Upload"` and similar, but I'm not sure how to tell the page when a PDF has been opened.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: What version of CF are you running?  a few things come to mind.  1) Save pagecontent to the DB, and then regenerate the PDF again, later at display.  2) You can cffile action="write" it to the file system or memory to generate the fle and then read it back into a variable to write it to the DB.  or 3) cffile action="write" the file to the file system, get the URL and path, and write that to the DB, so that instead of storing the file in the DB, your just storing the path and keep the file on the file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `filename` attribute of `cfdocument` to save the file directly to the server in a location of your choice.  [CFdocument Docs.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c21.html) You can also look into using [CFPDF](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7995.html)

> **Filename** - *Optional* - Pathname of a file to contain the PDF or
>   FlashPaper output. If you omit the filename attribute, ColdFusion displays the output in the browser.

```
<cfdocument filename = "c:/~" ...> <!--- filename attribute to save to server --->
   #pageContent#
</cfdocument>

<cfquery ...>
    <!--- sql --->
</cfquery>

<!--- once your document is saved and database updated--->
<cflocation url = "[your saved file].pdf"...>
<!--- or as Peter Suggested --->
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="[your saved file].pdf">
```

Comment: Converting to PDF twice is a waste of resources and time - either do [cflocation](http://cfdocs.org/cflocation) or [cfcontent](http://cfdocs.org/cfcontent) with file attribute.

Comment: I agree, i was thinking about taking out the second cfdocument and just offer the cflocation solution.  guess I'll do that.

Comment: Once you have the file written, you can use cfthread for the insert query so the user doesn't have to wait for that part.